# change database when clicking an <a> tag

Tags: counter

I am making a download counter. So i have a link, let's say:
`<a href="uploads/2/42.txt">rdp_download_31seqs</a>`

In my table "files" there is a column "timesdownloaded".
How can I increment this parameter by 1 when someone clicks on the link?
Thank you guys!

Comment: You've to make an ajax request to your server in order to execute the code that will update the timesdownloaded field in your table.

Comment: Errrrmm Which language by the way?

Comment: how do I do that? I'm dont have a clue about ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to start by creating a download file, preferably in php, which will accept a file parameter. An example would be "download.php?file=42.txt". From there the file will update the download count, and fetch the file from the uploads folder.